# for loop does not stop at each index

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, autoscroll

```
var switchTabs = function(index, el) {
            //alert("Call SwitchTabs");

            ribbon.slideTo(index);
            ribbon.currentSlideIndex = parseInt(index, 10);

            //console.log(ribbon.currentSlideIndex);

            dojo.query('.ibm-slider-wrapper #ibm-thumb-slider-tabs li.ibm-active').removeClass('ibm-active');
            dojo.query(el).addClass('ibm-active');      //applies class to current active li
            //fixTabHeight(index == 4);
        }
```

This below section of the auto scroll runs and does not stop 1 index at a time. It jumps straight to 6 and so my slider moves from 0 to 6th position. I want it to move 1 at a time after 8 seconds.

How can I make it stop each index and run the swapTabs(a, b); and then trigger an increment in the index variable inside autoScroll?

I tried using setInterval() but it still does function the way I want. Ideally I would like to use Switch statement for each index and trigger swapTabs inside setInterval so I can manage the timer for individual index key. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
var autoScroll = function(){            
            //alert("Inside AutoScroll");
            //var tabCount = $('.ibm-slider-wrapper #ibm-thumb-slider-tabs li');
                for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    var tabsIndex = $('.ibm-slider-wrapper #ibm-thumb-slider-tabs li a');
                        switchTabs(parseInt(tabsIndex[i].getAttribute('rel'), 10), tabsIndex[i].parentNode);
                        console.log(tabsIndex[i]);
                    }
        }   

        autoScroll();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` and have the function call itself:

```
var i = 0, interval = 8000, iterations = 6;

var autoScroll = function(){

    // function body here

    i++;
    console.log("Iteration #" + i);
    if (i < iterations) {
        setTimeout(autoScroll, interval);
    }  
}   

// start first run
autoScroll();
```

Comment: Thanks dbaseman! I wanted to know if it is possible to add a pause if the user clicked on the tab the autoScroll should pause, and if the user does not interact with any other tab for 8sec, it should pick up the position from the current tab position.

Answer (score 0):

Your code just goes from index 0 to 5 in rapid succession (within ms of each other) and the browser probably doesn't display anything until your script finishes on index 6.

If you want it to stop and show each tab, then you need to use something like `setTimeout()` and advance one tab each time the timer fires.

```
 (function() {
     var indexCntr = 0;
     var tabsIndex = $('.ibm-slider-wrapper #ibm-thumb-slider-tabs li a');
     function autoScroll() {
         if (indexCntr < 6) {
             switchTabs(parseInt(tabsIndex[index].getAttribute('rel'), 10), tabsIndex[i].parentNode);
             ++indexCntr;
             setTimeout(autoScroll, 5000);   // set the proper delay time here
         }
      }   

      autoScroll();
 })();
```

Comment: Thank you! for your help! I really appreciate you taking the time :)